# Parsing arbitrary given types in Python

Tags: python, parsing, types

I've got a dict of settings for each server in a Discord bot. I've stored the expected type for each setting so that it can be parsed to the correct value when a server admin changes a setting for their server (since parameters are passed as strings). Is there a Python library that allows you do something like:

```
parse(strValOfSetting, typeOfSetting)
```

and then get the correct type back? Or do I have to do something like

```
def parse(strVal, expectedType):
    if isinstance(expectedType, int):
        # parse strVal as int
        ...
    if isinstance(expectedType, tuple):
        ...
    ...
```

Parsing with a cast like `typeOfSetting(strVal)` doesn't work for things like booleans because anything other than "" parses to True. That's just an example.

If there's a library that would be cool. If not, I'll just homebrew something.

Thanks

Comment: I think the problem sounds simple enough that using a library (if there's one) is not worth the trouble. You just need a few functions like `parse_bool(string)`, `parse_int(string)`, etc. that take a `str` as a parameter and return a parsed value.

Comment: Alright. I'll probably just do that.

Comment: Depends on what types are supported, but you may be able to attempt to cast directly using `typeOfSetting` and then add a special case for `bool`